# Cannot load a temporary extension in Firefox - manifest error

Tags: firefox-addon

I receive the error that: borderify.zip does not contain a valid manifest

The extension was direct from Mozilla's github which I was directed to from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension

I then edited the manifest since I read that an id may be required because the add on isn't signed. The resulting manifest is here:

```
{
  "description": "Adds a solid red border to all webpages matching mozilla.org. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Examples#borderify",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Borderify",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/borderify",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"],
      "js": ["borderify.js"]
    }
  ],
  
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "addon@example.com",
        "strict_min_version": "42.0"
        }
    }
}
```

I opened the browser console to see the below trace:

```
While creating services from category 'app-startup', service for entry 'ExtensionsChild', contract ID '@mozilla.org/extensions/child;1' does not implement nsIObserver.
1680035666208   addons.xpi  WARN    Checking C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\distribution\extensions for addons 
[ACTION FAILED] TEMPORARY_EXTENSION_INSTALL_FAILURE: File D:\nicho\Documents\sandbox\browser extension\borderify.zip does not contain a valid manifest error-logging.js:16:17
    errorLoggingMiddleware resource://devtools/client/aboutdebugging/src/middleware/error-logging.js:16
    debugTargetListenerMiddleware resource://devtools/client/aboutdebugging/src/middleware/debug-target-listener.js:107
    Redux 2
    installTemporaryExtension resource://devtools/client/aboutdebugging/src/actions/debug-targets.js:142
loadManifest@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIInstall.jsm:684:11
error-logging.js:27:17
    errorLoggingMiddleware resource://devtools/client/aboutdebugging/src/middleware/error-logging.js:27
    debugTargetListenerMiddleware resource://devtools/client/aboutdebugging/src/middleware/debug-target-listener.js:107
    Redux 2
    installTemporaryExtension resource://devtools/client/aboutdebugging/src/actions/debug-targets.js:142`
```

I must be missing something really simple. I'm running Windows 10 and Firefox 111.0.1 (64-bit).

Answer (score 2):

As embarrassing as this may be I have to admit that I was trying to load the add on by selecting the zip file.

Instead, all I had to do was select any file within the extension's folder. (not the archive). I'm posting this here in case anyone else were to make the same mistake. Sorry and good luck.